# Are there any site moderators with very low reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer, moderators

Are there any moderators on SE that have very low reputation? I ask, since naturally, moderators are experienced users, who would have a decent amount of rep *unless they have given away many bounties*.

By that I mean site-specific moderators, not employees/CM/devs as they are entitled to moderate all SE sites.

Since "very low" can be subjective, I'd appreciate an SEDE query that can find all these low-rep moderators across all SE sites (if any) sorted by reputation.

Comment: Pro-tem moderators who *just* get appointed after the site finishes private beta will often have low reputation.

Comment: Yes, that is expected in early beta sites. I'm more interested in the exceptions, for example, those who moderate sites that have been launched for a longer time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1086915/moderators-by-reputation-networkwide), [this moderator](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/683/chenmunka) is the record holder with only 145 reputation. Do note that reputation only partially correlates with one's ability to moderate; this particular user is an experienced moderator on another site in the network.

Comment: Huh, there is only one moderator network-wide who is unable to vote in moderator elections on the site they moderate...other than them, the only people that applies to is staff, so I see why that may have been missed.

Comment: I think I was a mod for SO when I was on staff and would have had an effective SO rep of near 0. Ha! Of course, staff are a special exception.

Comment: @JoeFriend you probably had a diamond but was not elected (you wouldn't have shown up on [/moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) or on the global list for that matter: https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) which is what counts here as moderator (off-topic: I hope you're doing well)

Comment: @rene Definitely not elected. No one in their right mind would elect me to be a mod on SO. Ha! Doing well, thanks for asking. Miss connecting with all the community.

Comment: I made #22 on that list.  A proud moment....

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel. Is there a way to add a column for the total points of bounties offered by each of those moderators?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the query.