# Highest reputation moderators?

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer, moderators, statistics

Highest-rep users on the network are easy enough to find. What about highest-rep *moderators*? We all know that moderation ability doesn't necessarily correlate with reputation, and moderators on various sites range from just a few hundred rep up to a few hundred thousand, but is it possible (using Data.SE or any other tool) to get a list of the highest-reputation moderators? Let's say all moderators with over 100k reputation on their mod site?

Caveats:

- Elected/appointed moderators only, not staff with diamonds.
- I'm interested in reputation on an individual site where the person has a diamond, not their network reputation or their rep on other sites where they don't have a diamond. (In the case of multi-site mods, consider each of their mod sites independently and count them more than once if necessary - although I don't know if there's anyone who has *both* a diamond *and* more than 100k rep on two different sites.)
- I'm calling it now: the three highest-rep mods are Martijn Pieters on SO, Werner on TeX SE, and deceze on SO. Then maybe slm on Unix SE and Aaron Hall on SO, who are almost tied?

Comment: I guess discussion tag is better than support tag. What do you say?

Comment: @RandomPerson Well, I'm not looking to discuss anything, rather I want help with Data SE or whatever tool is necessary to get these statistics. So I thought [tag:support], but I'm not 100% sure if that's how the tags are used here.

Comment: I mean. there's few enough moderators for them to appear on one page on each site. just go there

Comment: A bit related: [Please provide a Moderators table in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115620). (It would be nice to see that implemented. OTOH I suppose that there are things which are more important than that.)

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but there are well over 100 sites. You'd have to visit all 100+ pages, wouldn't you? That seems very tedious.

Answer (score 10):

I've done a quick and dirty Python script which I could possibly tidy up and share but I think this is the output you're after (>= 100k on their site):

|  | name | reputation | _site |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) | 979228 | Stack Overflow |
| 2 | [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) | 570190 | TeX - LaTeX |
| 3 | [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) | 495566 | Stack Overflow |
| 4 | [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) | 462335 | Stack Overflow em Português |
| 5 | [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) | 394379 | Stack Overflow |
| 6 | [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila) | 373396 | Mathematics |
| 7 | [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) | 348322 | Unix & Linux |
| 8 | [Russia Must Remove Putin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541136/russia-must-remove-putin) | 346578 | Stack Overflow |
| 9 | [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) | 328650 | Mathematics |
| 10 | [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) | 294085 | Cross Validated |
| 11 | [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) | 282255 | Ask Ubuntu |
| 12 | [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) | 277270 | Unix & Linux |
| 13 | [L.Dutch](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/30492/l-dutch) | 245600 | Worldbuilding |
| 14 | [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) | 244404 | TeX - LaTeX |
| 15 | [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) | 232544 | Stack Overflow |
| 16 | [user229044](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/user229044) | 224693 | Stack Overflow |
| 17 | [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) | 222222 | Meta Stack Exchange |
| 18 | [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) | 221689 | TeX - LaTeX |
| 19 | [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) | 221031 | Ask Different |
| 20 | [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) | 219687 | Unix & Linux |
| 21 | [Ry-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry) | 210841 | Stack Overflow |
| 22 | [Kilisi](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/40669/kilisi) | 202059 | The Workplace |
| 23 | [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) | 195549 | Magento |
| 24 | [grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg) | 186484 | Ask Different |
| 25 | [Michael Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/michael-myers) | 184908 | Stack Overflow |
| 26 | [Qmechanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic) | 172354 | Physics |
| 27 | [JTP - Apologise to Monica](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/187/jtp-apologise-to-monica) | 170569 | Personal Finance & Money |
| 28 | [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) | 169583 | Stack Overflow |
| 29 | [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) | 168616 | Ask Ubuntu |
| 30 | [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) | 163792 | Drupal Answers |
| 31 | [Dale M](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/344/dale-m) | 158618 | Law |
| 32 | [gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) | 152856 | Blender |
| 33 | [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) | 144785 | Super User |
| 34 | [Adrian Larson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) | 143708 | Salesforce |
| 35 | [D.W.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/755/d-w) | 143153 | Computer Science |
| 36 | [Russell McMahon](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3288/russell-mcmahon) | 143059 | Electrical Engineering |
| 37 | [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) | 141428 | Science Fiction & Fantasy |
| 38 | [Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/4152/p%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%9c%ca%9fs%e1%b4%9b%e1%b4%87%ca%802) | 141304 | Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair |
| 39 | [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) | 139176 | Puzzling |
| 40 | [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) | 133741 | Stack Overflow |
| 41 | [Oddthinking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/23/oddthinking) | 133446 | Skeptics |
| 42 | [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) | 132896 | Mathematica |
| 43 | [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) | 132885 | Stack Overflow |
| 44 | [ChrisF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) | 131882 | Stack Overflow |
| 45 | [Journeyman Geek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek) | 131647 | Meta Stack Exchange |
| 46 | [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor) | 131574 | Science Fiction & Fantasy |
| 47 | [sysadmin1138](https://serverfault.com/users/3038/sysadmin1138) | 130953 | Server Fault |
| 48 | [tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) | 128385 | English Language & Usage |
| 49 | [rumtscho](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/4638/rumtscho) | 126304 | Seasoned Advice |
| 50 | [fgrieu](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/555/fgrieu) | 125233 | Cryptography |
| 51 | [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek) | 124673 | Super User |
| 52 | [schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder) | 123010 | Information Security |
| 53 | [J. M.'s persistent exhaustion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-s-persistent-exhaustion) | 120970 | Mathematica |
| 54 | [PearsonArtPhoto](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/25/pearsonartphoto) | 118789 | Space Exploration |
| 55 | [Tim](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/35989/tim) | 117729 | Cross Validated |
| 56 | [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) | 117563 | Stack Overflow на русском |
| 57 | [Pedro](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350/pedro) | 116996 | Mathematics |
| 58 | [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma) | 116241 | Movies & TV |
| 59 | [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) | 115396 | Game Development |
| 60 | [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan) | 111515 | Puzzling |
| 61 | [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) | 111074 | Mathematica |
| 62 | [T.E.D.](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/771/t-e-d) | 110270 | History |
| 63 | [ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind) | 108675 | Physics |
| 64 | [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r) | 108281 | English Language Learners |
| 65 | [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck) | 106820 | Super User |
| 66 | [Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters) | 105050 | Stack Overflow em Português |
| 67 | [fuxia](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/fuxia) | 104876 | WordPress Development |
| 68 | [Joonas Ilmavirta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/79/joonas-ilmavirta) | 104444 | Latin Language |
| 69 | [Jorgesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys) | 104436 | Stack Overflow en español |
| 70 | [Mitch](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch) | 103867 | Ask Ubuntu |
| 71 | [Majenko](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko) | 102814 | Arduino |
| 72 | [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) | 101562 | Ask Ubuntu |
| 73 | [Criggie](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/19705/criggie) | 100842 | Bicycles |
| 74 | [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) | 100164 | Stack Overflow em Português |

Comment: Just another suggestion: also include each mod's current overall reputation ranking on each site. I'd like to know which mods also have the highest rep on their sites and where else they stand.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I’m currently 7th. Until such time I catch up with Marc Gravell or T.J. Crowder catches up with me I suppose.

Comment: You're such a slacker @Martijn :p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I was using - https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/moderators/elected?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=meta - which is empty...

Comment: You also snubbed Glorfindel! On this very site, he has 222k and a diamond.

Comment: Glorfindel's score reminds me of https://xkcd.com/1105/

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a query like that a while ago to answer the *reverse* question: [Are there any site moderators with very low reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331971/295232)

The [same query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1086915/moderators-by-reputation-networkwide) works to answer your question (you just have to scroll a bit more). Here's the end of the list, your top three is right:

[image]